# Faster way to create tab deliminated text files?

Tags: c++

Many of my programs output huge volumes of data for me to review on Excel. The best way to view all these files is to use a tab deliminated text format. Currently i use this chunk of code to get it done:

```
ofstream output (fileName.c_str());
for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        output << arrayPointer[j * dim + i] << " ";
    output << endl;
}
```

This seems to be a very slow operation, is a more efficient way of outputting text files like this to the hard drive?

Update:

Taking the two suggestions into mind, the new code is this:

```
ofstream output (fileName.c_str());
for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        output << arrayPointer[j * dim + i] << "\t";
    output << "\n";
}
output.close();
```

writes to HD at 500KB/s

But this writes to HD at 50MB/s

```
{
    output.open(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(arrayPointer), std::streamsize(dim * dim * sizeof(double)));
    output.close();
}
```

Comment: does it have to be a custom written C++ program?

Comment: I suppose not. I just haven't learned how to use custom libraries and stuff yet...I don't know how to link it up properly.

Comment: I think the suggestion was to use \t instead of space was more about using char ('\t') instead of string (" ") than the actual space vs tab. Writing the string requires iterating to find '\0'. Not that I think that's the bottleneck in this case though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use C IO, it's a lot faster than C++ IO. I've heard of people in programming contests timing out purely because they used C++ IO and not C IO.

```
#include <cstdio>

FILE* fout = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "w");

for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) 
        fprintf(fout, "%d\t", arrayPointer[j * dim + i]); 
    fprintf(fout, "\n");
} 
fclose(fout);
```

Just change `%d` to be the correct type.

Comment: Thank you, this is significantly faster.

Comment: I'm actually curious as to how much, I've never tested it myself. Could you please quote some figures?

Comment: my hard drive was writing at speeds of about 10MB/s This was for doubles though. With the previous method it was only about 500KB/s

Comment: The difference is scary actually... Though I wonder what the Duff Device type thing would do since it would definitely give you better batching.

Comment: BTW, I know this is an old question, but I was curious, so I [ran some tests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32444720) to see if your claim holds. (It seems that it does, though the differences may or may not be significant.)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use endl. It will be flushing the stream buffers, which is potentially very inefficient. Instead:

```
output << '\n';
```

Comment: I suppose its faster, but its still unreasonably slow compared to a straight write of a double array straight to hard drive. Checking the hard drive usage, my program writes at a rate of 500KB/s when outputting tab delimintated files while when outputting straight binary data it goes to 50MB/s. why is it so slow?

Comment: Formatted output will always be considerably slower than raw output, but not normally by  a factor of 10x (assuming you got your MB and KB mixed up in your comment) - there is probably something else going on.

Comment: I checked again, it jumps around a little but the disc usage in write is somewhere around 30-45MB/s. I'm very sure its not my CPU to blame, its a Q6600 2.4ghz. I have a feeling that the text file is being chopped up into small little bits and being written to HD in small chunks rather than one massive buffer. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: You could try writing everything to a stringstream instead of a file stream and then output the stringstream in one chunk. This will take a lot more memory than using a file stream, and may or may not be faster. Alternativel, scrap C++ stream output and use C streams and fprintf() - this will almost certainly be faster than iostreams.

Answer (score 1):

does it have to be written in C? if not, there are many tools already written in C, eg (g)awk (can be used in unix/windows) that does the job of file parsing really well, also on big files.

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" file
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this, what is this?

Comment: He seems to want to speed up the output of  a program already written in C++. I don't see how awk can help do that.

Comment: @Faken, its a common *nix tool used for file processing. Also ported to Windows through GNU. It is also written in C, therefore you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Of course, only use it if you can afford to in your "project"

Comment: @Neil, i assumed he already have those huge data files generated by his programs.

Comment: Yea, my project is my thesis. So far theres no code in there that i haven't personally written (I'm a mechanical engineer, not a computer scientist so i have limited knowledge on coding and i don't really want to use something i don't understand less my proffessor ask me about it).

Answer (score 1):

It may be faster to do it this way:

```
ofstream output (fileName.c_str());
for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        output << arrayPointer[j * dim + i] << '\t';
    output << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to test [JPvdMerwe's claim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085777) that C stdio is faster than C++ IO streams.  (Spoiler: yes, but not necessarily by much.)  To do this, I used the following test programs:

#### Common wrapper code, omitted from programs below:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
int main (void) {
  // program code goes here
}
```

#### Program 1: normal synchronized C++ IO streams

```c++
for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
  for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
    std::cout << (i-j) << "\t";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

#### Program 2: unsynchronized C++ IO streams

Same as program 1, except with `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);` prepended.

#### Program 3: C stdio printf()

```c++
for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
  for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", i-j);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

---

All programs were compiled with GCC 4.8.4 on Ubuntu Linux, using the following command:

```bash
g++ -Wall -ansi -pedantic -DROWS=10000 -DCOLS=1000 prog.cpp -o prog
```

and timed using the command:

```bash
time ./prog > /dev/null
```

Here are the results of the test on my laptop (measured in wall clock time):

- Program 1 (synchronized C++ IO): **3.350s** (= 100%)
- Program 2 (unsynchronized C++ IO): **3.072s** (= 92%)
- Program 3 (C stdio): **2.592s** (= 77%)

I also ran the same test with `g++ -O2` to test the effect of optimization, and got the following results:

- Program 1 (synchronized C++ IO) with `-O2`: **3.118s** (= 100%)
- Program 2 (unsynchronized C++ IO) with `-O2`: **2.943s** (= 94%)
- Program 3 (C stdio) with `-O2`: **2.734s** (= 88%)

(The last line is not a fluke; program 3 consistently runs slower for me with `-O2` than without it!)

Thus, my conclusion is that, based on this test, C stdio is indeed about 10% to 25% faster for this task than (synchronized) C++ IO.  Using unsynchronized C++ IO saves about 5% to 10% over synchronized IO, but is still slower than stdio.

---

Ps. I tried a few other variations, too:

- Using `std::endl` instead of `"\n"` is, as expected, slightly slower, but the difference is less than 5% for the parameter values given above.  However, printing more but shorter output lines (e.g. `-DROWS=1000000 -DCOLS=10`) makes `std::endl` more than 30% slower than `"\n"`.
- Piping the output to a normal file instead of `/dev/null` slows down all the programs by about 0.2s, but makes no qualitative difference to the results.
- Increasing the line count by a factor of 10 also yields no surprises; the programs all take about 10 times longer to run, as expected.
- Prepending `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);` to program 3 has no noticeable effect.
- Using `(double)(i-j)` (and `"%g\t"` for `printf()`) slows down all three programs a lot!  Notably, program 3 is still fastest, taking only 9.3s where programs 1 and 2 each took a bit over 14s, a speedup of nearly 40%!  (And yes, I checked, the outputs are identical.)  Using `-O2` makes no significant difference either.

Answer (score 0):

```
ofstream output (fileName.c_str());
for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        output << arrayPointer[j * dim + i] << '\t';
    output << endl;
}
```

Use '\t' instead of "    "